# SharePoint Store is not connecting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-store

Facing below issue while connecting to SharePoint Store:

ULS:

> 03/08/2020 14:46:40.65    w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://sharepoint/_layouts/15/storefront.aspx?task=GetOfficeMarkets)  debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683
>   03/08/2020 14:46:40.65  w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|abc_xyz, ClaimsCount=41 debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683
>   03/08/2020 14:46:40.65  w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/  debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683
>   03/08/2020 14:46:40.66  w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   App Marketplace alokw   Medium  Starting storefront.aspx render for subcription id '87449b05-c4b0-46c6-8476-f828d3067d5c'.  debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683
>   03/08/2020 14:46:40.66  w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   App Marketplace ahnhh   Medium  Sending Request to Office.com with the following URL:https://store.office.com/commerce/query?lc=en%2DUS&type=3&build=15%2E0%2E4815%2E1000&av=OSU150&origin=EC101785291&corr=%7Bdebe3c9f%2Dab10%2Dd0f1%2D884d%2Dc53388b41683%7D  debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683
>   03/08/2020 14:46:42.64  w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   App Marketplace aep7f   Unexpected  Request to office.com with the following URL:https://store.office.com/commerce/query?lc=en%2DUS&type=3&build=15%2E0%2E4815%2E1000&av=OSU150&origin=EC101785291&corr=%7Bdebe3c9f%2Dab10%2Dd0f1%2D884d%2Dc53388b41683%7D&clientip=10.23.76.161 caused an exception. System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.     at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)     at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)     at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)     at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)     at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)     at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.OfficeProxy.OfficeProxy.SendWebRequest(String url, Boolean autoRedirect, String userIP, String postBody, String contentType, Encoding encoding, String jobRunIdLogPrefix) debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683
>   03/08/2020 14:46:42.64  w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (OfficeProxy.SendWebRequest). Execution Time=1975.23283983249   debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683
>   03/08/2020 14:46:42.64  w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   App Marketplace agdhz   Unexpected  Response from office.com was null or its HTTP status code was not 'OK'. Actual status code: 'InternalServerError'   debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683
>   03/08/2020 14:46:42.64  w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   General ajlz0   High    Getting Error Message for Exception Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Sorry, we can't seem to connect to the SharePoint Store. Try again in a bit.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.OfficeProxy.OfficeProxy.GetMarkets(String userDefaultBillingMarket, String userDefaultContentMarket, String userIP, List`1& markets, Boolean& validDefault)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.StorefrontBase.GetOfficeMarkets(HttpRequest request, List`1& markets, Boolean& validDefaults)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.StorefrontBase.TaskGetOfficeMarkets()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.StorefrontBase.TryRunTask(TryGetOutput taskMethod)    debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683
>   03/08/2020 14:46:42.64  w3wp.exe (0x2AAC)   0x328C  SharePoint Foundation   App Marketplace aep7g   High    An exception was thrown while running task 'GetOfficeMarkets'. Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Sorry, we can't seem to connect to the SharePoint Store. Try again in a bit.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.OfficeProxy.OfficeProxy.GetMarkets(String userDefaultBillingMarket, String userDefaultContentMarket, String userIP, List`1& markets, Boolean& validDefault)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.StorefrontBase.GetOfficeMarkets(HttpRequest request, List`1& markets, Boolean& validDefaults)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.StorefrontBase.TaskGetOfficeMarkets()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.StorefrontBase.TryRunTask(TryGetOutput taskMethod) debe3c9f-ab10-d0f1-884d-c53388b41683

Fiddler:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   Location:
>   /_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fstorefront.aspx%3ftask%3dGetOfficeMarkets&task=GetOfficeMarkets
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 SPRequestGuid:
>   c7c13c9f-1b07-d0f1-884d-c6b1ab45d689 request-id:
>   c7c13c9f-1b07-d0f1-884d-c6b1ab45d689 X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
>   SPRequestDuration: 2 SPIisLatency: 17 WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
>   WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4745 X-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2020
>   11:37:31 GMT Content-Length: 16 Proxy-Support:
>   Session-Based-Authentication
>
> 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot your issue as follow:

Make Sure the [Root Certificate Added into trusted Root Chain](http://sharepoint-sezai-moss-2007.blogspot.com/2012/12/sharepoint-server-2013-rtm-apps-sorry.html).

Make Sure the internet access to the Store feature ACTIVATED via central administration->manage web applications->manage features.

Comment: We already cross checked all the configurations. if we see the issue closely it is giving some transaport layer issue. Not able to understand this.  System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream